# Horizontally aligning button

Tags: html, css, button

I'm trying to horizontally align a button using CSS. Here's my markup:

```
<button type="button" class="primary-button download-button">Download</button>
```

And my relevant CSS:

```
.primary-button {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #004487;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, top, bottom, from(#5288bd), to(#2f659a));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5288bd, #2f659a);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4), inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.download-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
}
```

However, it's still aligned to the left. I thought setting `margin: 10px auto 0px auto;` would horizontally align it seen as it's now a block element but apparently not.

I've also tried wrapping it in a div and using `text-align: center` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/J8juB/) (Chrome).

Comment: Doesn't for me. Also Chrome, version 19. :/

Comment: you can center it by adding a fix width.

Comment: Try setting `float` to `none` on the button, and the container to `text-align` to `center`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give the button a width. See this **[jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/UJkTG/)**

```
.download-button {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
}​
```

Without a width, you're trying to center a block level element that is the full width of it's container. By explicitly setting a width (for example 130px on your button) the margin centering rule works.

Comment: Yeah, the margin: 0 auto trick doesn't work unless you define a width for the element.

Comment: Huh? Am I getting crazy? Is jsfiddle screwing things up? Because what OP has works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/J8juB/ ?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa - Fortunately you're not going crazy, however without the width rule, Chrome and Safari don't center the button. IE and FF do though.

Comment: Aha. I have Chrome 20 and 21 which do center it. Safari indeed doesn't. Tnx. Now I can die in peace ;) @j08691

Answer (score 0):

Actually setting `float` to `none` if both have `position: relative` should work:

```
.container{
  text-align: center;
 }
.button{
  float: none;
}
```